# Failed to resolve: com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.3

Tags: android, gradle, onesignal

I'm trying to setup OneSignal push notifocation in my Android app. I have changed my build.gradle to include the required dependencies (or so I think).

No matter what I do I keep getting

> Failed to resolve: com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.3

or

> Could not find com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.3

Can anyone give me a slight push please? Thanks in advance :-)

I should mention that I *have* checked the trouble shooting section on OneSignals home page. All is in order.

Here's the dependencies section of my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.0'
    compile files('src/main/libs/simple-xml-2.7.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/date4j.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Are u behind a proxy or something like that? Check your repositories

Comment: No proxy. And I can easily add OneSignal from the Module settings -> Dependencies. I search for OneSignal and add it as a Library dependency. Sync'ing my gradle file still fails though :-(

Comment: Do you have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of `build.gradle` ?

Comment: @NiteshVerma I didn't but adding it doesn't make a difference :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... what finally fixed this issue for me was to replace

```
mavenCentral()
```

with

```
jcenter()
```

go figure... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The OneSignal SDK is hosted on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.onesignal%22%20AND%20a%3A%22OneSignal%22)  so I would first make sure you can access this from your system. Next double check the following as well.

1. Make sure you're using Android Studio version 1.4.0 or newer.
2. Go to File>Settings. Search for Offline work and uncheck that option.
3. Add the following to your .gradle file.

Root `build.gradle`

```
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
```

4. Try restarting Android Studio and then going to Tool>Android>Sync Project again.

5.Try building OneSignal's [example Android Studio project](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/tree/master/Examples/AndroidStudio). If this works then the problems is related to your project.

Screenshots for some of these steps below.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-android

Comment: Thanks @jkasten. As mentioned in the OP I have already been through the steps you mention from your troubleshooting section. No dice - sry :-(

Comment: @CJe Just added step 5 to my answer to help narrow the issue.